# In Monopoly Deal, can you pay with houses or hotels?

Tags: monopoly-deal

Can you pay with houses or hotels or do they remain with you forever?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Monopoly Deal FAQ](http://www.hasbro.com/monopoly/en_US/discover/faq.cfm) (scroll down to near the end):

> Q - WHICH CARDS CAN I USE TO PAY OTHER PLAYERS? (E.G. FOR RENT, BIRTHDAYS ETC.)
>
> A - You can choose to pay:
>
> - from your Bank (with money or Action cards that you've Banked as money),
> - with Property cards, or
> - with a combination of both.
>
> Remember, you can only pay with cards that are on the table in front of you, never with cards from your hand.

You cannot pay with Houses or Hotels you have on properties because they are not in your bank nor are they Property cards themselves.  If you had Banked them, you could use them to pay for things.

Answer (score 5):

> However, if a player charges you money and you decide to pay with some of the property from your completed set that includes a House and/or Hotel, the House or Hotel must be placed on the table next to your property section until you complete another set and it can be placed on top. You can also pay with your house or hotel card if you choose.

source :http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=house#top

Comment: whoa... .we've been moving the houses with the property. Good lord those rules are written poorly and incompletely.

Comment: Note that link is a *fan compilation* of rule Q&As, not an official rules page. So while I do appreciate the answers on that page, I think its entirely reasonable to disagree on corner cases like this as long as your play group establishes the details ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

The rules (which you can check on [this Monopoly wiki page](http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Monopoly_Deal_Rules)) say that you absolutely cannot play cards from your hand. You can put hotels and houses into your bank though.

Answer (score -3):

I’m pretty sure you can pay with hotels/houses since they have an amount on them in the corner! We played a tutorial game here: https://www.100kelvins.com/blog/how-to-play-monopoly-deal-card-game/